# Change postgres password using remote ssh

Tags: bash, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm running a postgres database on a Google Cloud instance that we drop and recreate daily as part of our nightly build.
Currently this is being done manually and I want to automate it.

```
gcloud compute ssh --zone europe-west2-c postgres@postgresql-dev -- "dropdb mydb"
gcloud compute ssh --zone europe-west2-c postgres@postgresql-dev -- "createdb mydb"
gcloud compute ssh --zone europe-west2-c postgres@postgresql-dev -- "psql postgres -c 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE mydb to myuser;' "
```

This works fine to drop and recreate the database, the problem comes in when I have to re-setup the password ...

```
gcloud compute ssh --zone europe-west2-c postgres@postgresql-dev -- "psql postgres -c 'ALTER USER myuser WITH PASSWORD 'passwordhere' ; "
```

`gcloud` command is already using the double quotes, `psql postgres -c` is already using the single quotes, what quotes should I be using to put the password in quotes?

I've tried escaping the quotes, but it doesn't work:

```
WITH PASSWORD \'passwordhere\'
```

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "\" LINE 1: ALTER USER myuser WITH
>   PASSWORD \passwordhere'

or

```
WITH PASSWORD \"passwordhere\"
```

> bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `'' bash:
>   -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

How do I escape those quotes?

Comment: Isn't the problem with `\"` the fact that you don't close the `'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this seems to work:

```
gcloud compute ssh --zone europe-west2-c postgres@postgresql-dev -- "psql postgres -c 'ALTER USER myuser WITH PASSWORD '\''passwordhere'\'' '; "
```

-

```
WITH PASSWORD '\''passwordhere'\''
```